# Defining and calling variables in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to define variable in shell script as:

```
value1 = 40  (this can be number or character)
```

and want to use as in a text like:

```
$value1_position.xyz (I basically want 40_position.xyz)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

this should do:

```
${value1}_position.xyz
```

---

beware that the variable should be declared with this syntax

```
value1=40
```

notice the absence of spaces around the `=`

Comment: Thank you @DRC. I was giving spaces .. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To define a variable, simply make sure there are no spaces between the variable name and value

```
value1=40
```

To use that variable in bash substitution, creating what you want, use the `$` replacement symbol like so:

```
${value1}_position.xyz
```

To append that to your text file

```
echo "${value1}_position.xyz" >> file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @foips. I was giving spaces. Appreciate your quick answer.